# 'TemplateDoesNotExist' can't get the solution

Tags: django, templates, settings, not-exists

I am starting in Django, but I am stuck with this problem

I have this structure in my VSCode Workspace

```
-Project1
   __pycache__
   __init__.py
   asgi.py
   settings.py
   urls.py
   views.py
   wsgi.py
-templates
   mytemplate.html
db.sqlite3
manage.py
```

I am trying to use a template that I built

**urls.py**

```
from Project1.views import salute

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('salute/', salute),
]
```

**views.py**

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.shortcuts import render

class Persona(object):
    
    def __init__(self, nombre, apellido):

        self.nombre = nombre

        self.apellido = apellido

def salute(request): 

   p1=Persona('Peter', 'Parker')
   
   temas_del_curso = ['Plantillas', 'Modelos', 'Formularios', 'Vistas', 'Despliegue']

   fecha_de_hoy = datetime.datetime.now()

   return render(request, 'miplantilla.html', { 'nombre_persona' : p1.nombre, 'apellido_persona' : p1.apellido, 'fecha_de_hoy' : fecha_de_hoy, 'temas' : temas_del_curso })
```

They suggest I copy the directory path where my template is saved

**settings.py**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
       'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': ['C:/Users/machine/Desktop/Django/Project1/templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
}
```

Also use the form Django suggests `'DIRS': BASE_DIR / 'templates'` and the form `[os.path.join (BASE_DIR, 'templates')]` but the error continues

Comment: I guess it must be: `'DIRS': ['C:/Users/machine/Desktop/Django/templates']`

Answer (score 0):

This is standard settings.py for full project.
Since I can't see your full source code, I can't solve out issue directly.
Take a reference from it.

```
import os
from decouple import config
from unipath import Path
import dj_database_url

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).parent
CORE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config('SECRET_KEY', default='S#perS3crEt_1122')

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config('DEBUG', default=True, cast=bool)
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
# load production server from .env
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['localhost', 'ec2-3-133-208-9.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com','www.spreadmore.space','spreadmore.space', config('SERVER', default='127.0.0.1')]
# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'django_plotly_dash.apps.DjangoPlotlyDashConfig',
    'app',
    'authentication', 
    'rest_framework',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',

    'django_plotly_dash.middleware.BaseMiddleware',
    'django_plotly_dash.middleware.ExternalRedirectionMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'core.urls'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "home"   # Route defined in app/urls.py
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "home"  # Route defined in app/urls.py

TEMPLATE_DIR = "E:/Python/ocm_project/app/templates"  # ROOT dir for templates

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'core.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME'  : 'E:/Python/ocm_project/db.sqlite3',
    }
}

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# custom settings
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "authentication.User"
X_FRAME_OPTIONS = 'SAMEORIGIN'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',

    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashAssetFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashComponentFinder',
    'django_plotly_dash.finders.DashAppDirectoryFinder',
]

# Plotly components containing static content that should
# be handled by the Django staticfiles infrastructure

PLOTLY_COMPONENTS = [
    'dash_core_components',
    'dash_html_components',
    'dash_bootstrap_components',
    'dash_renderer',
    'dpd_components',
    'dpd_static_support',
]
MEDIA_URL = 'app/ocm_data/TW/SPX/'
MEDIA_ROOT = "E:/Python/ocm_project/app/ocm_data/TW/SPX/"
```